# How handle or convert // to / in url address in python django and apache -- linux

Tags: python, django, linux, apache

At first, thank you for reading :X

## Problem + Description:

I'm redirecting http traffic from any ip address on port 80 to 10.0.0.1:8080 (django) via linux apache and iptables.

When web user issue a request to this url (hello.gggstatic.com/generate_204******), I  handle path to `**generate_204**` url address, via this rule: `re_path('.*generate_204.*', lambda r: HttpResponseRedirect('splash/')),`.

```
 Buuuuut, users are seeing `//splash/` instead of `/splash/` in browser.
`http://10.0.0.1:8080//splash/`  #django 404 not found
 users must see:    
`http://10.0.0.1:8080/splash/`   #django can handle it and via "include('splash.urls')"
```

**Problem:** How to manage/remove/handle "//" in url address bar !!??

**Log:**

```
[09/May/2020 13:43:36] "GET //generate_204 HTTP/1.1" 302 0
Not Found: //splash/
[09/May/2020 13:43:36] "GET //splash/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2328
```

my urls.py file in django-project:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path('/static/', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATICFILES_DIRS}), 
    re_path('.*generate_204.*', lambda r: HttpResponseRedirect('splash/')),
    path('', lambda r: HttpResponseRedirect('splash/')),
    #path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('splash/', include('splash.urls')),
]
```

my urls.py file in django-application:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path('^$', views.start, name='start'),
    re_path('index/$', views.start, name='start'),
    path('validation', views.validation, name='validation'),
    path('bye', views.goodbye, name='goodbye'),
]
```

**I edited my question:**

```
path('splash/', include('splash.urls')),
#above line failed to handle //splash behavior.
to:
re_path('.*splash/', include('splash.urls')),  
#above line works. but it's not ok. and we can have everything here between ip/domin:8080 and /splash: http://10.0.0.1/******/splash/. and this behavior is bad for url handling.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a [custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) and set it up like Djangos [CommonMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/middleware/common/).

The `CommonMiddleware` handles redirects for the settings `PREPEND_WWW` and `APPEND_SLASH`.

So this is more of less the same usage as you want it: You get a request with a specific url and want to redirect it to another one (or in other words: correct the url).

So a short (dummy) example with a little code from said middleware:

```py
class RedirectDoubleSlashMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    response_redirect_class = HttpResponsePermanentRedirect

    def process_request(self, request):

        uri = request.build_absolute_uri().replace('http://', '').replace('https://', '')

        possible_uri = uri.replace('//', '/')

        if uri != possible_uri:
            return self.response_redirect_class('{}://{}'.format(request.scheme, possible_uri))
```